# Added a function in a class, to a class or into a class?

Tags: word-usage, expression-choice, programming

Did I add a function *in a class*, *to a class* or *into a class*?
Which of the given expressions would I use to describe the changes in this code?

```
//class A before
class A 
{
};

//class A after
class A
{
    void aFunction();
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you extend the class / attach code to the class the right term to use would be:

> '**Added** a function **to** a class'

In the [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/add) they used this example for adding something (an additional element, ingredient, etc.):

> ‘**Add** the flour **to** the eggs, stirring continuously’

You contribute something to an existing object.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/add) contains the answer to your question.

**TL;DR** :

> 5. (intransitive) To make an addition. To add to, to augment; to increase. *It adds to our anxiety.‎*